# XenServer VM SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, xenserver

I am trying to create a Ubuntu VM in XenServer and log into it with SSH. I was already able to do this using the same image, but now I just cannot figure out how I got the IP of the newly created machine. I only have access to the Host through SSH so I have been using the CLI to create the VMs. I know the IP of the newly created VM is available somewhere since I was able to log into the first one I created. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thank you,
Zach

Comment: The answer is described in here - it's really simple: http://support.citrix.com/article/ctx119906

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you provision the IP. If you have no clue I would search the router's arp table and try all of them. Worst case use a port scann of your subnet. You should be able to connect on the console of the vm and run `/sbin/ip a s`

Comment: How can I connect to the console of the vm to execute this if I don't know the IP to ssh into? Does Xenserver provide some other means of accessing the shell of a VM?

Comment: Use VNC to connect on the guest console. See: http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/HowTos#head-d84290f0772207af49ea1c30394042c74dedff5c

Comment: Try adding `-c` when starting the VM: `xm create -c config_file`

Answer (score 0):

If you use XenCenter to manage the Xenserver, you can find the IP addresses of a guest OS by looking at the Network Tab of that server.
If not, you can use the API:

http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244784&tstart=0

http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=272373&tstart=0

In both cases you need to have the xen-tools installed on the guest.